# How to resolve hostnames with nmap to perform scans?

Tags: network, nmap

I went through old threads on this forum and tried `--resolve-all` but it doesn't seem to work.

If I use `nmap -sn <hostname>` It throws an error `Failed to resolve <hostname>`

If I use `nmap -sn --resolve-all <hostname>` It still throws an error `Failed to resolve <hostname>`

How to resolve this hostname and then perform nmap scan? It's not resolving the IP.

Comment: I have to ask. Are you actually providing a hostname or are you literally using `<hostname>`? For examples (and for a test that will work) use `example.com` instead.

Comment: Can you ping or reach the IP or domain at all through other means? This could be simply a network issue.

Comment: Is your DNS server OK?

Answer (score 1):

Hostname resolution is done using DNS. If the DNS server does not return an IP address to the given hostname then nmap cannot magically do better. All one can do is choose a different name server than the default using the `--dns-servers` option. One need to specify one which can resolve the hostname and which is reachable by nmap.